# Do all of the Stack Exchange staff have access to a user's information?

Tags: discussion, privacy, stack-exchange-team

When a user of Stack Exchange runs into trouble, e.g. gets into an argument with another user or moderator and incurs a suspension, I understand that volunteer diamond moderators and some Stack Exchange staff (Community Managers + the staff that gets the Contact Us messages) have access to a user's history.

I was wondering whether anyone who works at Stack Exchange also has the same access to a user's history - people from the CEO, to the VP of Marketing/Sales, all the way down to, let's say the kitchen staff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Privacy policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy)

Comment: Ugh ... it costs so much rep to post a question here ...

Comment: Only if it's not well received

Comment: The question had a potential to become a well-received question, but mentioning something (that in my opinion) absurd in general case, unfortunately, backlashed it: kitchen staff. How often companies have their janitorial staffs known about their staffs' or clients' history?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Practically speaking, as a moderator - *unless* there's a specific request by a user or mod for CM or Dev assistance, its unlikely they'd look.

While I *don't* work for SE - as a moderator I've had to agree to a [moderator agreement](https://superuser.com/legal/moderator-agreement)

as per the [privacy policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy)

> Security – All records containing personal or financial information are considered to be our property and are afforded confidential treatment at all times. We work hard to protect against the unauthorized access, use, alteration or destruction of personal or financial information. All such electronic information is stored on restricted database servers, and is generally kept until such time as you may ask us to edit or delete it, as described below. We only disclose such information to our employees, agents or affiliates that a) need to know that information in order to process it for us or to provide other services, b) have agreed not to disclose it to others, and c) in response to lawful requests by public authorities, including to meet national security or law enforcement requirements.

So, practically anyone with access would need to have a need for it (so not the pastry chef) and agreed to not share it. Pretty sure this would be a NDA of some flavour. In any case, the personal information we have is *limited* and AFAIK there's been no incidents of mods or employees abusing it.

As for the CEO - eh, it depends. Jeff was *super hands on* in the early days, when it was a small team. I've not really interacted with Joel in the context of my site. Marketing/Sales would likely be more interested in *broader* trends, as would the data science folks. We don't really talk much to marketing but they're more concerned with SE's job sites (see privacy policy!) and SE enterprise , and once again, aggregate information is more useful than individual information unless something breaks.

Answer (score 26):

Nope. Only staff with moderator privileges have access to your history.

[image: users/history is ModeratorOnly]

OTOH, everyone who *does* have access to your history has the means to block your access if it turns out you're in the habit of abusing it.

Answer (score 23):

No. We restrict user data based on whether it's needed for employees to do their job. For instance, even though I have a diamond on every site, I can't see any personal information on [our Jobs site](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs). (Well, I can see my own personal information, but that's it.) Meanwhile, employees who don't have a diamond don't have access to personal data on the Q&A sites. So the majority of employees don't have access at all.

We do this not only for your benefit, but also ours. Nobody wants to violate the [privacy policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy).