# Remove diamonds in reviews done by moderators before becoming moderators

Tags: feature-request, review, moderators, timeline

I was going through this post's timeline: [Is a clean install better than upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/q/5466)

Looking at the events in the timeline is quite confusing TBH.

First, let's take a look at this event: https://askubuntu.com/posts/5466/timeline#review_669540

[image]

Zanna was not a moderator in 2017. She became a moderator [in 2020](https://askubuntu.com/election/7). So, having the diamond in this case is a bit confusing but it's OK as all the reviewers voted to leave the question closed.

Let's take a look at the next event: https://askubuntu.com/posts/5466/timeline#review_833759

[image]

In this review, Zanna cast vote to reopen the question. But since majority of the reviewers voted to leave the question closed, the question was not reopened.
This will look confusing to someone new to the network as many know that moderator actions are final; so they would assume that the question should have been reopened because of Zanna's vote. Most of the people new to the site would not know when Zanna became a moderator, so things will look contradictory to them.

There are other reviews as well in the timeline in which Zanna has participated (but was not a mod back then).

So please remove the diamond from reviews which were done before becoming a moderator to avoid confusion.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the diamond is displayed next to a current mod's username basically anywhere it appears on that site, even if it's associated with an action from before they became a mod. Likewise, the diamond is not displayed next to a former mod's username anywhere on that site, even if it's associated with an action they took when they were a mod. (I'm guessing that it'd be a non-trivial amount of work for the devs to change that behavior if they wanted to, but that's just speculation.)

Comment: Close votes also have ♦'s. I've seen a post where most people who closed as a dupe have diamonds and one even had a gold tag badge.

Comment: It does allow for nice trivia, as I posted here: [Are there any questions closed by 5 moderators?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316248/295232) cc @Peilonrayz

Comment: The diamonds are linked to the usernames, not the actions - If I was no longer a moderator, my solo closes wouldn't have a diamond next to it

Comment: @V2Blast https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1192772 

Answer (score 12):

> A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?

When a user runs in a moderator election, that's what's asked of them. And I think that's how it should stay.

It's an easy to explain rule: the diamond is always attached to a mod's name (except in user-generated content). To change it would require developer time better spent on other issues.

With your suggestion, things start getting confusing in other ways. When the diamond isn't always next to the mod's name, you might think there are two different accounts at play. And what would the pattern be for when a diamond is displayed and when it's not? (Reviews show the same information that's shown elsewhere in the system. In addition you can see comments under the post.) Do we give ex-moderators their diamonds on posts they unilaterally closed?

Comment: Well, there is a plan to start a [former moderators page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371293). I am not sure if there is a plan to start a "*Former moderator*" symbol shown beside the username.

Comment: If they were not a moderator at the time they took an action they could have [this symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwKgm.png) and if the action was performed in the moderator (or staff) capacity they could have the current indicator. This would work forward and backwards, is that what [your comment proposes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371293); if so such information is better when included in your question, instead of a comment.

Comment: @Rob I think asking a new question would be better than making substantial changes to my question.