# Does Stack Exchange or its subsidiaries keep any records on how often a user has been banned or warned by a moderator?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, moderators, ban

About 5 years ago I was banned once from Stack Overflow for trolling in the comments of a question. I can remember that my ban was automatically lifted after some of my own questions had received some up-votes.

At the time I didn't really care about the whole ordeal but now I kind of do. The reason for this is that on the one hand I've accumulated a decent amount of reputation points since then and I wish to post the flair of my SO account on my LinkedIn account. But I'm hesitant to do so because there might still be some log or record attached to my account that recorded the fact that I was banned and may even include the reason why I was banned.

**Does Stack Exchange or its subsidiaries keep any records on how often a user has been banned or warned by a moderator?**

If so, for how long is such a record stored?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updates to Privacy Policy (September 2021)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370216/282094),  because the last link leads to: https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy#share-data

Comment: You appear to be conflating multiple things, which makes what you're asking unclear. Moderators *can't* impose question or answer bans. Those are entirely automatic. The system will remove those bans after your posts are upvoted, if those votes make you no longer fit the undisclosed question and/or answer ban criteria. Moderators can send private messages/warnings and impose *suspensions*. Such suspensions *can not* be removed automatically as the result of posts being upvoted. Suspensions are for a specified number of days, but could be manually removed early by a moderator.

Comment: @Rob the fact that a question contains a link to the privacy policy that contains the information does not make it a duplicate.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Fundamentally – outside the time you are *actually* suspended, there's no visible *external* record of suspension.

There *is* a log kept of suspensions, question/answer bans, and moderator messages internally. It's visible to the mods of the site(s) those events occurred on, as well as [*some* SE employees](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305940/do-all-of-the-stack-exchange-staff-have-access-to-a-users-information/305941#305941) –  and goes back to the start of your account but it's not going to get shared with a potential employer or other users.

I wouldn't worry *too* much about past issues and youthful indiscretions coming back to haunt you.

Comment: I'm not sure how closely even a potential employer would investigate accounts either. Even if someone mentioned your suspension publicly, say on Meta (i.e. this question), it's not in the part of the site where they would be looking.

Comment: @Laurel I think the OP was afraid that that information might be (now or in the future) accessible somehow via the user's profile.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, what about the offending comments that were deleted, are they still stored somewhere as well?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225182/did-you-know-that-10k-users-can-see-deleted-comments I'm not sure if its locked down yet, but deleted comments generally are hidden to non mods, not redacted.