# Is it possible to find out if/when my account has received a (review) ban before?

Tags: support, user-accounts, moderators, review-suspension, ban

I'm wondering if there's a way for a user to find out if (and when) their account has ever received a review ban (or any other kind of ban for that matter) on a given site.

Can this information be determined somehow by the user or does it require asking help from a moderator? If you're a site moderator, would you be okay with receiving such requests?

Comment: Related: [Does Stack Exchange or its subsidiaries keep any records on how often a user has been banned or warned by a moderator?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375332/294055)

Comment: Related feature request in [Rand al'Thor's answer to "Improving Review Queues - Design overview II: Changing review bans and other new features"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/346906).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well - wierdly enough, the only site I've ever been review banned on happened while I was a sitting moderator. From what I can tell on the user end  there's no indicator on your profile, or at all other than on the specific review queue while you review. Mods *do* have access to this information however, and can look it up.

*Personally* I'd be fine with it - it's your own information and it's not hugely taxing to check for a single user. YMMV with other mods.

Comment: Given that it's data about you, a [GDPR data request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340953/271271) should have the information, but I haven't verified that it's in there.